# How to share information about SCM changes between jobs in Hudson?

Tags: hudson

Is there any way to get information in a downstream job about SCM changes in the upstream one?

For example if we have a build job (with SCM polling) which triggers some testing jobs, how testing job could retrieve and show in dashboard information about SCM changes in build job which triggers this test job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about Hudson, but for Jenkins we use [Blame Subversion plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BlameSubversion).

Comment: Searching for "Blame" reveals two Hudson plugins - will inspect them. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Hudson [Blame Subversion plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/BlameSubversion) worked for me. Thanks again.